# Subquery is not giving desired result when using in update statement in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to update a column 'validate' in [sdw].[WS_INV_CONTACT] using the below query

```
BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE [sdw].[WS_INV_CONTACT]
SET    validate = ( CASE
                      WHEN EXISTS (SELECT A.address_zip_code
                                   FROM   [sdw].[WS_INV_CONTACT] AS A
                                          LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ZipCode] AS B
                                                 ON A.address_zip_code = B.Zip
                                   WHERE  A.address_zip_code = SUBSTRING(address_zip_code, 1, 5)
                                          AND B.zip IS NULL) THEN 'N'
                      ELSE 'Y'
                    END );
```

Subquery used in above update statement results in 6 rows and I want to update validate column with 'N' only for those six rows, but query is updating all the rows in the table.

Please can anyone suggest me where I'm doing wrong or any better solution.

Highly appreciated

Comment: What are you trying to do with `A.address_zip_code = SUBSTRING(address_zip_code, 1, 5)`?

Comment: As the data in Address_zip_code is in this format 31515-0290 but  I want to compare only first 5 number of zipcode .

Comment: You're comparing the column with itself. `A.address_zip_code = SUBSTRING(address_zip_code, 1, 5)` will be true for any row where `address_zip_code` is less than or equal to 5 chars,

Comment: Okay. My bad. I wanted to compare  A.address_zip_code  with B.zip , as data in B.zip is in 5 chars. is this I need to do?   on substring(A.address_zip_code ,1,5) = B.Zip
where B.zip is null

Comment: That still won't work in your original query as it isn't correlated to the outer query. See my answer though it may have the N and Y inverted. Wasn't sure whether `validate` means "is valid" or "needs validation"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need something like the following

```
UPDATE A
SET    validate = CASE
                    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                                 FROM   [dbo].[ZipCode] AS B
                                 WHERE  B.Zip = LEFT(A.address_zip_code, 5)) THEN 'Y'
                    ELSE 'N'
                  END
FROM   [sdw].[WS_INV_CONTACT] AS A
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE a 
SET    validate = ( CASE 
                      WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT a.address_zip_code 
                                       FROM   [dbo].[zipcode] AS b 
                                       WHERE  a.address_zip_code = b.zip 
                                              AND a.address_zip_code = 
                                                  Substring(address_zip_code, 1 , 5)) THEN 'N' 
                      ELSE 'Y' 
                    END ) 
FROM   [sdw].[ws_inv_contact] a
```